# Non-Latin Characters in permalinks

Tags: permalinks, encoding

I was opened this idea 7 months ago:
http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/non-latin-characters-need-love 
Still i couldnt find a solution for it.

**Simply what i want?**
Want to use "şŞ İı Ğğ Üü Öö çÇ" turkish characters in permalinks / slugs.

Comment: Do you want to replace `Ş` with `S` or should the permalink contain `Ş` literally?

Comment: want to use "ş" in permalink

Comment: I created plugin for this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-turkce/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must go about the language functions-interface. See my example for german users: http://wordpress-buch.bueltge.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/de_DE.phps
We must also build differences on the permalinks for aour charachters in our language

```
    /* define it global */
    $umlaut_chars['in']    = array( chr(196), chr(228), chr(214), chr(246), chr(220), chr(252), chr(223) );
    $umlaut_chars['ecto']  = array( 'Ä', 'ä', 'Ö', 'ö', 'Ü', 'ü', 'ß' );
    $umlaut_chars['html']  = array( '&Auml;', '&auml;', '&Ouml;', '&ouml;', '&Uuml;', '&uuml;', '&szlig;' );
    $umlaut_chars['feed']  = array( '&#196;', '&#228;', '&#214;', '&#246;', '&#220;', '&#252;', '&#223;' );
    $umlaut_chars['utf8']  = array( utf8_encode( 'Ä' ), utf8_encode( 'ä' ), utf8_encode( 'Ö' ), utf8_encode( 'ö' ),utf8_encode( 'Ü' ), utf8_encode( 'ü' ), utf8_encode( 'ß' ) );
    $umlaut_chars['perma'] = array( 'Ae', 'ae', 'Oe', 'oe', 'Ue', 'ue', 'ss' );

    /* sanitizes the titles to get qualified german permalinks with  correct transliteration */
    function de_DE_umlaut_permalinks($title) {
        global $umlaut_chars;

        if ( seems_utf8($title) ) {
            $invalid_latin_chars = array( chr(197).chr(146) => 'OE', chr(197).chr(147) => 'oe', chr(197).chr(160) => 'S', chr(197).chr(189) => 'Z', chr(197).chr(161) => 's', chr(197).chr(190) => 'z', chr(226).chr(130).chr(172) => 'E' );
            $title = utf8_decode( strtr($title, $invalid_latin_chars) );
        }

        $title = str_replace($umlaut_chars['ecto'], $umlaut_chars['perma'], $title );
        $title = str_replace($umlaut_chars['in'], $umlaut_chars['perma'], $title );
        $title = str_replace($umlaut_chars['html'], $umlaut_chars['perma'], $title );
        $title = sanitize_title_with_dashes($title);

        return $title;
    }
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'de_DE_umlaut_permalinks' );
```

Comment: For those concerned to provide a patch for wordpress core, a related ticket is http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9591

Comment: sorry for late response but i think i couldnt explain my problem. I want to use "şŞ İı Ğğ Üü Öö çÇ" chars in permalinks.

Comment: An example.. "примерно" you can use these russian chars in permalinks but "şŞ İı Ğğ Üü Öö çÇ" becoming "ss-ii-gg-uu-oo-cc"

Comment: i write some info about this on: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10249#comment:36

Comment: well.. after some tries i found a solution but need core edit so i opened a ticket about putting a new filter probably. ticket is: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15248

Comment: after long long searches, seems its not something supported in php community yet.. unicode permalinks basically what i want seems.. I have an ideas page about it: wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/non-latin-characters-need-love